# C# decrypt algorithm method; how do I encrypyt it?

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-4.0, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to do the algorithm.

I found an example algorithm, but I do not know how to encrypt it. I tried very hard but I could not.

Can you help me please?

```
private static string Decrypt(string string_key)
{
    UTF8Encoding uTF8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

    RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");
    byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");

    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(bytes, bytes2);

    byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(string_key);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(array);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    byte[] array2 = new byte[checked(array.Length + 1)];
    int count = cryptoStream.Read(array2, 0, array2.Length);

    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    string_key = uTF8Encoding.GetString(array2, 0, count);
    return string_key;
}
```

Comment: This is no encryption code, because it contains `rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor`. Anyway, there is so much wrong with this code, that it would be more advisable to chose an actual library that does this. Please throw this code away if you wanted to use it for a production system.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the wrong code.
I corrected the code.

Comment: And this is not producing any exception? Note that `bytes` and `bytes2` have an invalid length. Also, the stream is never flushed, so there is a block missing.

Comment: Please take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx on how to properly encrypt and decrypt using Rijndael. However AES https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx is in general more preferred.

Answer (score -10):

To encrypt strings, I'd recommend you to use XOR instead of Rijndael.

Why? Because the encryption algorithm == the decryption algorithm.
I use it myself all the time. You can use Rijndael if you really want though or if it's needed, there are perfect examples online.

```
        public static string XOR(string input, string key)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            sb.Append((char)(input[i] ^ key[(i % key.Length)]));
        String result = sb.ToString();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is equally bad code if not even worse. First it would create invalid strings as not all UTF-16 values (which is what char and string uses) have valid Unicode representations. Especially if your resulting chars land in the high and low surrogate area (D800-DFFF) this may break string methods as these expect that a high surrogate is followed by a low surrogate and  a low surrogate is preceded by a high surrogate. Second XOR requires (or at least if it should be secure) that the key is at least as long as the input, which in most cases is impractical.

Comment: Well, it works completely fine for me, even when using keys of just 3 characters.

Comment: This is basically no encryption at all (see https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2063). And with such a short key, one could just stupidely bruteforcing the key in a reasonable short time by just trying all combinations.

Comment: If you actually do use this yourself all the time, you should stop that.  Right now.  Bad.  Bad.

Comment: You as well as OP should stop doing "encrypting" on your own RIGHT NOW. Every customer that gets into contact with your attempts of securing any of their data / communication is at risk.